# Unknown red rectangle appears in map window

Tags: qgis, extents

I would like to know where this red rectangle comes from? It's not a polygon or a line, it can't be activated or removed or anything else. It just appeared during the project work (adding shp-files, georeferencing rasters and digitalizising,...)

Maybe it's about extents?!

[image: screenshot of red rectangle]

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you have a Grass Mapset open?  If so, it's the GRASS '[region](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/g.region.html)' being shown.

EDIT: Note that you can toggle it on/off from the Grass toolbar "Display Current Grass Region" button and edit it with the "Edit Current Grass Region" button.

Comment: I closed the Mapset, it disappeared. that was the reason. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Untoggle the Editing icon, it might be because you're in Editing mode.

[image: Editing icon]

Comment: QGIS editing doesn't have the concept of a 'region' and thus would have no reason to have an extent rectangle shown. As per my answer, the rectangle is the Grass region being shown.